# UINavigationBar with solid color - ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm using an `UINavigationController` with its default `UINavigationBar` and I'm trying to turn the translucent effect off, so I can have a solid color on it. Apparently, it doesn't work with code but it is possible with storyboard with just one click (weird ?!!)

my code:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:APP_DELEGATE.map];
[navController setToolbarHidden:YES];
[navController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
[navController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor turquoiseColor]];
//    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor turquoiseColor]]; | also doesn't work
```

Why doesn't it work ? How can I fix that ?
Thanks.

Comment: @PhamHona : You should accept the right answer to keep the good work up.

Answer (score 13):

This is the right way to do it. User `appearance` proxy methods.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Thats all & you are done. Use whatever colour you want. The above code makes the NavigationBar as opaque (i.e. Solid color).

Answer (score 4):

And for all you Swiftians out there:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

The above should work for Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.

Comment: I prefer Swifters :P

Answer (score 2):

use this way for solid color of navigation bar i have faced this issue lots of time

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:APP_DELEGATE.map];
[navController setToolbarHidden:YES]; 
navController.navigationBar.barTintColor =[UIColor turquoiseColor];
[navController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is making a UINavigationController subclass and overriding `initWithRootViewController:` - and doing there exactly what you are doing (set translucent to NO and apply a bar tint color, except that now of course we are operating on `self`).

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. In addition, the storyboard way doesn't work either (it works in a test project but not in my main project, even I followed exactly every steps). I thought this would be done in just 1 or 2 lines of code but people are struggling with it too, so sad.

Comment: jezz ! f***ing sh**, it works, my code works, your code works. Just wrong color name. I thought `turquoiseColor` is darker than `greenseaColor` and `UINavigationBar` makes it looks washed out. 2 hours wasted on nothing. damn ! sorry man.

Answer (score 0):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UINavigationBar.appearance.translucent = NO;
```

This will provides solid background color red and text color white with property as non-translucent.